# issue with accessing c++ library using fastcall. (javascript, nodejs, foreign function interface)

Tags: node.js, cmake, shared-objects, node-ffi, fastcall

I tried using fastcall, this is my first time using fastcall and foreign function interface, I tried to load datatable.dll it is throwing error, tried passing every possible library path (absolute and relative).
using nodejs, fastcall, javascipt

```
const fastcall = require('fastcall');
const Library = fastcall.Library;
const ref = fastcall.ref;
const lib = new Library('datatable.dll')
lib.isSymbolExists('fread')
```

error i received is

```
TypeError: Cannot load library or library not found: datatable.dll
at Library.initialize (c:\Users\nband1\fastcall\fastcall\lib\Library.js:82:37)
at Library.isSymbolExists (c:\Users\nband1\fastcall\fastcall\lib\Library.js:111:14)
```

Comment: DLLs are searched in PATH env variable, in the process' .exe directory and the working directory.

Comment: Ok, Here I'm trying to load datatable.dll https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table. which is r dependent library. tried loading other libraries (testlib and benchlib) running fine. Is there a way to load his r dependent library? Thank you